In developing discord App. How can I use session for token
I am making discordBot(express + ts server). It use discord OAuth2 token because I need to use API(ex /users/@me/connections). So I tried to manage access_token with session, But It's not working like my expection. the session can't find token that saved.
And this is my app OAuth flow
enter image description here
at point1, save session
req.session.token = accessToken

at point2, use session
if(!req.session.token){
  res.send(makeAuthAllowComponent({content:`need allow to access your profile`}))
}

I found  the sessionId are change every slash command like this:
enter image description here
So I guess the reason why I can't use session is changing of sessionId
My Question : How can I use session with slash command?
Now, My solution is :
request /users/@me, when response access_token(point1). And use redis like user.id : access_token. And get token from redis when It's needed(point2, because I can get user id in req). Is that good Idae?
It's my first time to make discordApp server, So I don't have enough working in slash command logic. Please give me your opinion. thank you
